# Statistical data on the software business

Tags: statistics

Is there a good source information on the software business (in US)?  In particular, I'm looking for things like:

1. Number of people employed in the software business (not just developers, but support staff as well).
2. Break down by age, sex, etc. of current software developer workforce.
3. Number of businesses whose primary product is software development.
4. Number of universities offering BS, MS, PhD in computer science.

You get the idea...I realize that most of this information is scattered on various websites, but I wanted to know if there was a single source that had a "all the stats on the computer software industry."

Answer (score 0):

Some answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203824/how-many-professional-software-developers-are-there-worldwide) are about US and could be of interest. No single resources, though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the questions you pose, but you could try http://www.wolframalpha.com/. Notice that below the "knowledge search results" it links to references, that may be of value.